# Deployment of .net application with react results in appsettings.json not found

Tags: reactjs, asp.net

Simply said,

IIS returns  `Unhandled exception. System.IO.InvalidDataException: Failed to load configuration from file 'D:\web\CHARTMAKER\appsettings.json'. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException`

However, the file exists on the path and IIS has full access to this folder.

[image]

Any ideas? I do not know, which information are needed to help me.